# Почему не отправляются куки?

Tags: php, cookie

Здравствуйте, ХешКод!

Хочу добавить переменную в куки, но выдаёт ошибку. Код `php`, который я для этого использовал:

```
<?php
session_start();

$val = "Хай";
setcookie("ref", $val);

?>
```

Ошибка:

> `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:\home\automatic.ru\www\index.php:9) in Z:\home\automatic.ru\www\header.php on line 9`

Весь код:

```
<html>
<head>

<?php
session_start();

$elseref = $_GET["ref"];
if ($elseref != '') {
    $val = "Хай";
    setcookie("ref", $val);
}

require("config.php");

if (isset($_SESSION["username"]) && isset($_SESSION["password"])) {
    $username = $_SESSION["username"];
    $password = $_SESSION["password"];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_user WHERE username = '$username' and pass = '$password'") or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

    $_SESSION["status"] = $row["status"];
}
?>

</head>
<body>
<center><img src="img/logo.png" height="100">
</b></h1></center>
<hr />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: шде то вы уже отправили тело ответа, после чего нельзя добавить куки. Я так понимаю это не весь код, где то что то инклудитися

Comment: on line 9, а у тебя 7 строк! проблема не здесь

Comment: Да вроде нет, щяс добавлю весь код.

Comment: Проблема не здесь потому что я немного код заменил, но они оба не работают и выдают одну и туже ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();

$elseref = $_GET["ref"];
if ($elseref != '') {
    $val = "Хай";
    setcookie("ref", $val);
}

require("config.php");

if (isset($_SESSION["username"]) && isset($_SESSION["password"])) {
    $username = $_SESSION["username"];
    $password = $_SESSION["password"];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_user WHERE username = '$username' and pass = '$password'") or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

    $_SESSION["status"] = $row["status"];
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<center><img src="img/logo.png" height="100">
</b></h1></center>
<hr />
</body>
</html>
```

и кстати, ваш код уязвим, я зайду и не зная пароля :) и почитайте как работает ф-я isset, вы ее не правильно применяете

Comment: А что там не так?

**P.S** ошибка осталась.

Comment: Проблема решена, товарищ :)

Answer (score 0):

До `setcookie` и до `header()` нельзя применять ни одного `echo`, `print` и т.д. У вас получается что

```
echo "<html>
<head>";
```

А потом уже `setcookie`. Попробуйте `setcookie` засунуть до `<html>`.

Comment: Не помогло.

Comment: А у вас с сессиями все нормально? Может они борохлят? Второй вариант: можете работать с куками на JS. Если попросите, могу выслать функцию.